# iOS UIpageviewcontroller as detail in uisplitviewcontroller. Ignores back pan gestures

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a UIPageViewController in the detail pane of a UISplitViewController - allowing paging through a diary like table of days with events while still showing a table of menu items in the master view.

Everything works but the previous day swipe gestures are ignored.

No problems if I change this to a modal segue.

I assume the problem is due to the presentation of the data view controller with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

```
SessionDataViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SessionDataViewController"];    
dataViewController.dataObject = [self.pageData objectAtIndex:index];
return dataViewController;
```

Any advice on how I can get the the DataViewController to accept page back swipe gestures in a detail pane in the same way as it does in a modal view would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem sounds like its caused by the UISplitViewController. It has a gesture recognizer thats used for showing and hiding the masterViewController which is preventing the UIPageViewController from ever getting it. You'll just need to disable the gesture recognizer on the UISplitViewController with the following line.

`[splitViewController setPresentsWithGesture:NO];`

Comment: Thank you very much - exactly the issue.